# How to limit Connectify wifi hotspot speed on a notebook?

Tags: wireless-networking

Before I ask I want to describe the situation that I have.

I use a notebook (Windows 7) as a client in a network using a LAN cable. On this laptop I'm using a software called Connectify to make this laptop into a hotspot.

My questions is:
1. How can I limit the download / upload speed from a user connected to the Connectify?
2. How can I limit the speed of the internet that which comes from Connectify?
3. Is there a software like Connectify that has ability to limit the wifi hotspot bandwidth speed?

Comment: After quick searching, `Netlimiter` should be able to do that.

Comment: If Netlimiter able to do this, may I see how to do that step by step? Please..

Comment: Never tried doing this myself. My point is all of these questions are google-able and were discussed.

Comment: I already install Netlimiter on this notebook, but I can not find a way how to limit the speed of wifi hotspot. Netlimiter works fine to do the job on this machine but I can not find a way how to limit the speed of wifi hotspot with it in Connectify.

Comment: @user5226582 : On SuperUser, and StackExchange in general, the aim is to be a repository of all possible questions and answers. If you have found an answer somewhere else, you are encouraged to post a copy here as an answer.

Comment: I already too to set limit to all Connectify stuff (Connectify Daemon Service, Connectify Helper Application, Connectify Hotspot, and connectifynetservices.exe) in Netlimiter Panel but it does not works. It still shows that user are still using all the bandwidth of this network.

Comment: Another two tools being mentioned are `Bandwidth Controller` and `Traffic Shaper`. I've not seen the step-by-step guide but would try limiting bandwidth of all connectify related services.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I'll try it one by one..

Answer (score 1):

[Solved] Use a router with QoS fixed my problem.